# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound for login.jsp

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-status-code-404

my jsps are under views,

**web.xml** :

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
<display-name>Spring-MVC-Security</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
         /WEB-INF/servletDispatcher-servlet.xml,/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**servletDispatcher-servlet.xml** :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<!-- <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> -->

<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.controller"></context:component-scan>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.spring.util"></context:component-scan>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/list" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="lokesh" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

**Controller** :

```
package com.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping({"/","/login"})
public String login()
{
    return "login";
}
}
```

When I am trying to hit

```
http://localhost:8080/Spring-MVC-Security/ ,
url is getting redirected to 
http://localhost:8080/Spring-MVC-Security/login
```

but I am getting 404 error from tomcat and getting following warning at the console:

```
Jan 13, 2014 12:03:41 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Spring-MVC-Security/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'servletDispatcher'
```

It seems like servletDispatcher is hit again after view resolution.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Your code seems fine, try to put a debug inside your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you're loading the `servletDispatcher` context twice. The dispatcher servlet will automatically discover the `/WEB-INF/servletDispatcher-servlet.xml` file based on conventions - so this does not need to be specified in the `contextConfigLocation`

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
         <!-- Remove servletDispatcher-servlet.xml -->
         /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Try changing your dispatcher servlet mapping from `/*` to `/`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servletDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also - since your login controller is not doing anything other than returning the `login` view, you could replace it with a view controller.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/login" />
```

Comment: Change of /* to / in servlet mapping resolved the issue. Thanks